# is Shutdown/reboot command behaviour is same across all the file system

Tags: linux

"The shutdown command used to kill all the running processes, unmount all the file systems and finally tells the kernel to issue the ACPI power command"

is above mentioned  behaviour is same across all the file system  ?

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear why you are asking that, but I'll take a stab at it: Yes, all filesystems are unmounted. The code run at unmount varies per filesystem.

Comment: is all the running processes are killed before unmounting the file system ?

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/64280/what-is-the-difference-between-reboot-init-6-and-shutdown-r-now

Comment: Is there any chances  of un mounting of file system getting failed due to some running processes ? during shutdown/reboot operation ?